# Pipe to the second thing is having no affect

Tags: gulp

I have a simple task in my gulpfile it is:

```
gulp.task('pack_and_obfuscate', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/scripts/creds.js')
        .pipe(packer50x({
            mode: 'none'
        }))
        .pipe(jsobfuscator({
            encodeString: true,
            encodeNumber: true,
            replaceNames: true,
            moveString: true,
            exclusions: ["^_get_", "^_set_", "^_mtd_"]
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.packed.obfuscated'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts/'));
});
```

However the `.pipe` to `jsobfuscator` is having no affect. If I remobe the first `.pipe` to `packer50x` then `jsobfuscator` has an affect. I can't understand this. How come `jsobfuscator` is not doing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) before and after the first pipe to see what files goes through (or maybe also after `jsobfuscator`'s pipe).

If this doesn't give you any hint try post also your requires here.

Btw, is it even possible to combine `packer50x` and `jsobfuscator`?

Comment: Thanks very much Martin, I actually wrote the task `packer50x` and I based it on `jsobfuscator`, I started gulp and node just a week  ago. Maybe the code doesn't allow piping of file contents? This is the code for jsobfuscator: https://github.com/Ficik/gulp-javascriptobfuscator - i seriously appreciate this I am loving gulp and here is packer50x - https://github.com/Noitidart/gulp-packer50x/

Comment: Mistake was that I wrote `packer50x` module, and that i based my work on another module that was not pipeable. Thanks Martin!